# how to eradicate 'None' from the end of a recursion

Tags: python, recursion, towers-of-hanoi

I have the following code:

```
n=input('How many disks?')

def MoveTower(n, source='A', dest='C', store='B'):
    if n==1:
        print source + '->' + dest
    else:

        MoveTower(n-1, source, store, dest)
        MoveTower(1, source, dest, store)
        MoveTower(n-1, store, dest, source)

print MoveTower(n)
print str(2**n-1), 'moves total'
```

The following code return the moves required to solve a Tower of Hanoi with n disks and calculates how many disks required successfully, but after all the moves, there is a 'None'
I want to get rid of this- can you please help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remove the `print` statement, just call `MoveTower(n)` without printing it's return value:

```
MoveTower(n)
print str(2**n-1), 'moves total'
```

*All* python functions return *some* value. If you don't return anything explicitly, the default is value is `None`. Calling `print MoveTower(n)` prints the default `None` returned by `MoveTower()`.

Comment: Thank you very much, that is a perfect concise and easy to understand answer. I will take this to the future of my programming.